# Oracle SDO_NET cannot valid network

Tags: oracle, plsql, network-programming, spatial

I have a problem with Oracle Spatial Network package. I'm creating NODE, LINK and PATH based on LRS. When I try call:

```
  SELECT SDO_NET.VALIDATE_NETWORK('network_tracking') FROM DUAL
```

then I recive error:

```
  LRS schema error: column:[GEOM_ID/SDO_GEOMETRY] in table:LINIE_LRS does not exist.
```

But in my table LINIE_LRS I have type SDO_GEOMETRY but is named LRS. What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. To create VALID network based on SDO_NET the target table should have SDO_GEOMETRY column and GEOM_ID as identifier. My table have ID as identifier, so I must create view based on this table, because this table is using in another application.